# Case When Then Adjacent Switching Scenario Correspond to an ID

Tags: mysql, sql

Let suppose

'Mary is a teacher in a middle school and she has a table seat storing students' names and their corresponding seat ids. The column id is a continuous increment. Mary wants to change seats for the adjacent students.'

The sample table looks like this:

```
+---------+---------+
|    id   | student |
+---------+---------+
|    1    | Doris   |
|    2    | Abbot   |
|    3    | Green   |
|    4    | Emerson |
|    5    | Jeames  |
+---------+---------+
```

Mary wants to switch Adjacent Student, the output looks like this:

```
+---------+---------+
|    id   | student |
+---------+---------+
|    1    | Abbot   |
|    2    | Doris   |
|    3    | Emerson |
|    4    | Green   |
|    5    | Jeames  |
+---------+---------+
```

I have come up with the solution using **Case When and Then statement**.

Solution :

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN((SELECT MAX(id) FROM seat)%2 = 1) AND id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM seat) THEN id
        WHEN id%2 = 1 THEN id + 1
        ELSE id - 1
    END AS id, student
FROM seat
ORDER BY id
```

Is there any other easy way using case statement or any other approach through which we can solve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: from the problem statement, it sounds like you are supposed to update, not select?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of self join using `LEFT JOIN`, `CASE WHEN` and `COALESCE` as alternative.

```
select s1.id, coalesce(s2.student,s1.student)
from sample s1
  left join sample s2
    on s1.id + case when s1.id%2=1 then 1 else -1 end = s2.id
```

[image]

`COALESCE` and `LEFT JOIN` are just needed to keep the record for `Jeames`, which not join with `s2`

You can test on [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=c977c18131363f2fe07a91b9d0955076) db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lead()` and `first_value()`:

```
select id,
       coalesce(lead(student) over (order by id),
                first_value(student) over (order by id)
               ) as student
from t;
```